# Unfamiliar shell syntax in ack-grep install script

Tags: bash, shell, installation, ack

From the ack installation page (http://betterthangrep.com/install/) there is a one-liner installation with curl:

```
curl http://betterthangrep.com/ack-standalone > ~/bin/ack && chmod 0755 !#:3
```

I understand that it's getting the file from the website and saving it to ~/bin/ack, then setting permissions, but what does that last part ( !#:3 ) do ? (I do not recognize the syntax and Googling didn't yield any helpful results)

Comment: I'm the maintainer of betterthangrep.com and I didn't even know what it did, except to know that it worked.  Thanks for asking what I should have asked when someone submitted it to me. :)

Comment: Please don't use salutations like ["Thanks in advance!"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). And don't add them to other people's posts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the section called HISTORY EXPANSION in man bash, particularly the Word Designators subsection.  `!#:3` refers to the third word of the pipe, which is (in your example) `~/bin/ack`.  In order, the words of the command are `curl`, 0;  `http://betterthangrep.com/ack-standalone`, 1; `>`, 2;  `~/bin/ack`, 3; `&&`, 4;  `chmod`, 5; `0755`, 6; `!#:3`, 7.
That is, `!#:3` is a way to repeat the filename without using a separate variable or literal text.

Regarding the question about `>` and whitespace, note that `>` is a metacharacter, which man bash defines as a “character that, when unquoted, separates words.  One of the following: |  & ; ( ) < > space tab”.  So whitespace does not affect whether `>` counts as a token.  But note that in the following example, the first `3` is quoted so that bash doesn't interpret it as part of a `3>` redirection.  When the line was entered, bash echoed the expanded line and then executed it.

```
$ seq '3'>bbb;cat !#:3 !#:2 ccc; head !#:3 !#:8
seq '3'>bbb;cat bbb > ccc; head bbb ccc
==> bbb <==
1
2
3

==> ccc <==
1
2
3
```

Comment: Is that tokenized according to meaning or whitespace?  If it was `curl url>file`, would there now be two words or four?

Comment: It's tokenized according to whitespace. The count starts with zero, so `curl` is 0, the URL 1, the redirection operator 2, and the file 3.

Comment: @AndyLester, also see added example

Answer (score 3):

`!#` means to execute the command typed so far, but you can specify a parameter with `:n`. `:0` would be the first word (`curl`), `:1` the second one (`http...`) and so on.