# What is the meaning of !#:3?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, zsh, ack

```
 curl http://beyondgrep.com/ack-2.02-single-file > ~/bin/ack && chmod 0755 !#:3
```

What is the meaning of `!#:3`, from [ack installation guide](http://beyondgrep.com/install/)?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12885417/unfamiliar-shell-syntax-in-ack-grep-install-script

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In bash or zsh `!` denotes a history command (not a shebang line which is `#!`, and has nothing  to do with bash or zsh as such).

`!#` means the entire command line typed so far, and `:3` selects the third word, in this case `~/bin/ack`.

So the command is equivalent to:

```
 curl http://beyondgrep.com/ack-2.02-single-file > ~/bin/ack && chmod 0755 ~/bin/ack
```